# Why is my sequence generating incorrectly?

Tags: java

The goal of the code is to generate a sequence that operates as follows:
The first number is given, 2. To find the next number in the sequence: multiply all numbers in the sequence together than add 1. The smallest prime divisor of that number is the next number in the sequence. The first three number are [2, 3, 7]. So 2*3*7 + 1 = 43. The smallest prime factor is 43. So 43 is the next number. However when my code reaches the 5th number in the sequence it generates 139, instead of 13. 2*3*7*43 + 1 = 1807. 1807/13 = 139. So 13 should be next.

Problem: When my code reaches the 5th number in the sequence it generates 139

Note: Using BigInteger because reaching the 8th, 9th,... do not work with Int

```
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    
    
    public class LPMSeq {
    
    public static BigInteger spd(BigInteger y) {
    
        ArrayList<BigInteger> primes = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    
        int retval = 0;
        int Nth_prime = 25200;
        BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("1");
    
        primes.add(TWO);
    
        int i = 1;
        
    //generates N prime numbers using isProbablePrime
        while (i < Nth_prime) {
            bi = bi.add(TWO);
            if (bi.isProbablePrime(80)) {
                i++;
                primes.add(bi);
                
            }
        }
    
        BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");
    
        
        // finds smallest prime divisor
        for (int n = 0; n < Nth_prime; n++) {
            BigInteger modded = y.mod(primes.get(n));
            if (modded.equals(zero)) {
                retval = primes.get(n).intValue();
            }
        }
    
        return BigInteger.valueOf(retval);
    }
    
    public static  ArrayList<BigInteger> LpmSeq(int k) {
            //ArrayList holding the sequence
        ArrayList<BigInteger> Seq = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        
        BigInteger two = new BigInteger ("2");
        //Add two to sequence (first number in sequence)
        Seq.add(two);
        while (Seq.size() < k) {
            BigInteger x = new BigInteger ("1");
            for (int i = 0; i < Seq.size(); i++) {
             x = x.multiply(Seq.get(i));
              }
            BigInteger y = x.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            BigInteger spd = spd(y);
            Seq.add(spd);
        }
        
    
        return Seq;
    }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        //Create Scanner
        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
            
    
        
        // Variables
        int k = 0;
        
        
        //Prompt user and get input
        System.out.println("How many elements would you like in the sequence? (Please enter an integer)");
        k = userinput.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println(LpmSeq(k));
         
    
         
            
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: So you're adding the result to the sequence, and not the divisor?

Comment: Think it’s time to dig up the debugger.

Comment: No it adds the divisor. "retval = primes.get(n).intValue();"

Comment: If it was adding the divisor it would be adding the 13, and not the 139.

Comment: @AntonH That is for why there is this question.

Comment: Also, just to remove an unnecessary line, `BigDecimal` has `new Decimal("0")` built in: `BigDecimal.ZERO`, alongside `BigDecimal.ONE` and `BigDecimal.TEN`. You need not redefine them.

Comment: Don't vandalize your own post. If you really need to remove it (*why?*), you can hit the delete button underneath.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to hide your code from teacher or someone else, they can still see it by clicking the "edited X mins ago" and see changes made to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop that finds the smallest prime factor doesn't work if `y` isn't prime:

```
// finds smallest prime divisor
for (int n = 0; n < Nth_prime; n++) {
    BigInteger modded = y.mod(primes.get(n));
    if (modded.equals(zero)) {
        retval = primes.get(n).intValue();
    }
}
```

It finds the *largest* prime factor, because it doesn't stop when it finds the first prime factor.  Because the factorization of 1807 is 13 x 139, it skips 13 and returns 139.

Place a `break` after you assign `retval`:

```
for (int n = 0; n < Nth_prime; n++) {
    BigInteger modded = y.mod(primes.get(n));
    if (modded.equals(zero)) {
        retval = primes.get(n).intValue();
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, I find it curious that you're checking all primes through the 25,200th (and re-calculating all 25,200 of them each call).  You only need to check primes through the square root of `y`.

Comment: Beat me to the evaluation on why there exists `y`! I was thinking, hang on it's never used.

Comment: Why only to the square root of y, what if y is a prime number?

Comment: If you find a prime factor greater than the square root, then you should have found a prime factor less than the square root first.  E.g. 143 (sqrt. about 11.96), if you find 13, you should have found 11 first.  For 1807 (sqrt. about 42.51), if you find 139, you should have found 13 first.